# C# repeating data help

Tags: c#, .net, video, repeater

I've just created my first attempt at a video gallery and I am wondering how I would go about displaying more than one video, providing the user uploads more!!!

How it currently works is that they enter set information into a database and I then pull this onto the page, inside a literal.

Here is the code behind

```
DT_Control_VideoGallery VG = 
  db.DT_Control_VideoGalleries.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PageControlID == int.Parse(HF_CPID.Value));

if (VG.Source.ToString() == "YouTube")
{
    LB_Video.Text = "<iframe width=" + VG.Width + "height=" + VG.Height +
                    "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + VG.ReferenceKey.Trim() +
                    "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
}
else
{
    LB_Video.Text = "<iframe width=\"" + VG.Width + "\"height=\"" + VG.Height +
                    "\"frameborder=0\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" +
                    VG.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "?title=0&amp;byline=0\"></iframe>";
}
```

Now this is fine say if the user has only one video they want to display at a time, but how would I go about displaying more than one???

Thanks!

Comment: Well you have `SingleOrDefault` which would mean only one record

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable from a security standpoint. Make sure you check your user input very well as you're putting user input directly in the resulting html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add multiple iFrames beneath LB_Video. Not the most elegant solution, but it will work OK and is as simple as you can make it...

- Select the if / else statement
- Refactor with Extract Method and create a new method 'CreateVideoHtml' that can be called multiple times
- Change 'Text' = to 'Text +=' so multiple lots of HTML can be be added
- Add Where() in place of SingleOrDefault()
- Add 'ToList()' (returns all items) or 'Take(n)' (to retrieve n at most)
- Call the new CreateVideoHtml method from a loop

Note there's also an issue with your code - SingleOrDefault() can return null, so the next line (.Source) will fall over if VG is null... you need to watch out for stuff that can be null!

So ...

```
        public void YourMethod()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var videoList = db.DT_Control_VideoGalleries.Where(x => x.PageControlID == int.Parse(HF_CPID.Value)).Take(3);
            foreach(var video in videoList)
            {
                CreateVideoHtml(video);
            }

            foreach(var video in videoList) 
            {
                CreateVideoHtml(video);
            }

            // Nothing returned from your query - CreateVideoHtml was never called!
            if (LB_Video.Text == String.Empty)
            {
                LB_Video.Text = "No video!";
            }
        }

        private void CreateVideoHtml(DT_Control_VideoGallery video)
        {
            if (video.Source.ToString() == "YouTube")
            {
                LB_Video.Text += "<iframe width=" + video.Width + "height=" + video.Height + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            }
            else
            {

                LB_Video.Text += "<iframe width=\"" + video.Width + "\"height=\"" + video.Height + "\"frameborder=0\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + video.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "?title=0&amp;byline=0\"></iframe>";
            }
        }
```

Note that if you use 'var' in declarations, this decouples your code from specific Types, meaning code can be moved around more freely.  Next, if you have a lot of videos you might be better to use a StringBuilder (from System.Text namespace).  To do that, tweak the above as follows:

```
public void RenderVideo()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var videoList = db.DT_Control_VideoGalleries.Where(x => x.PageControlID == int.Parse(HF_CPID.Value)).Take(3);
            foreach(var video in videoList)
            {
                // sb is passed in by reference, so we can see any changes here
                CreateVideoHtml(sb, video);
            }

        // Nothing returned from your query - CreateVideoHtml was never called!
        if (sb.Length == 0)
        {
            LB_Video.Text = "No video!";
        }
        else
        {
             LB_Video.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    // this is static - all dependencies are passed in by reference
    // the calling code can see the modifications to sb
    // all this method does is create Html so you could unit test it
    private static void CreateVideoHtml(StringBuilder sb, DT_Control_VideoGallery video)
    {
        if (video.Source.ToString() == "YouTube")
        {
            sb.Append("<iframe width=" + video.Width + "height=" + video.Height + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
        }
        else
        {

            sb.Append("<iframe width=\"" + video.Width + "\"height=\"" + video.Height + "\"frameborder=0\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + video.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "?title=0&amp;byline=0\"></iframe>");
        }
    }
```

Rendering Html in string handling code is never the most elegant way to go, but it will work reliably for you, and it's also easy to see (from the HTML) what has been produced, so it's easy to see if anything is going wrong....

The next refactoring you might try could be

```
LB_Video.Controls.Add(new VideoControl(video));
```

...and let that VideoControl class wrap the specifics of how the HTML is generated.

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the LINQ query at the end to fetch several elements, and you simply want more `iframe`s added, you can probably do something like this:

```
var VGs = db.DT_Control_VideoGalleries.Where(someSelector);
foreach( var VG in VGs )
{
  if (VG.Source.ToString() == "YouTube")
  {
    LB_Video.Text += "<iframe width=" + VG.Width + "height=" + VG.Height + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + VG.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
  }
  else
  {
    LB_Video.Text += "<iframe width=\"" +  VG.Width + "\"height=\"" + VG.Height + "\"frameborder=0\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + VG.ReferenceKey.Trim() + "?title=0&amp;byline=0\"></iframe>";
  }
}
```

You should probably also use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the strings, and put it into `LB_Video.Text` in the end, but this should show you the concept at least.